# Netbeans 8.2 and JDK 1.8+ open Java file force closes - no errors

Tags: maven, netbeans

I had this Maven project I programmed where I had opened its files and running smoothly.

But yesterday, it had this manner where whenever I open any java file from my project, it closes it (not NetBeans itself). But whenever I do a test run on the code, it runs smoothly and without errors.

I tried fixing **JDK1.8** and downloading and re-installing **NetBeans** again, but still can't open any file.

How can I fix this problem?
There no signs of pop up errors, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question; the "forceclose" tag refers to Android functionality. You do have a strange problem there... is there anything that changed in the setup?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Hi :D thanks for the reply, i  really appreciate it. Currently right now, I'm developing this project of mine just using a notepad++ to open the java.file and edit/code from there then saved it and run it on netbeans to see if it works or to detect errors. As you can see, it's helping me out on code but it's really inconvenient since i can't edit jframes in a graphical manner.

Comment: @S.L.Barth when it comes to change of setup, none. though at times i'm working this one out like changing JDKs, uninstall, reinstall, redownload JDKs and Netbeans itself. Since i'm doing this, everytime i open my porject on netbeans, it'll require java platform, i would use of course the platform that works on it but some java files would generate red marks on the project explorer like there's an error if the name declaration of java platform is not the other way around. i.e JDK_1.8 name clears the red marks but still can't open, JDK_1.8-bit32 name pops up the red marks and still can't open